# How do I get epubs from my Inbox to my PC Kobo?

Tags: epub, kobo

Not interested in eReaders. I just want to take epubs in my mailbox and put the into my desktop Kobo.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Kobo desktop will only access books purchased from Kobo. For other epubs, Calibre or Google Play books would be a better choice.